# How to download a view-only PDF?

Tags: pdf, download, read-only

I am trying to download a PDF file from a site that lets me only view it. 
I visited the site a few months back, and back then I could easily download PDFs. 
Recently however, they seem to have undergone a layout change of their website.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366310/can-view-pdf-on-website-but-cannot-download-it), and put ".pdf" after the link, but it said webpage not found.

Can anybody tell me how to download the PDF?

The PDF I am trying to download is [here](http://www.thinkiit.in/iitjee/lecture-notes/physics/class-11/relative-motion/english/#).

Comment: I am not sure, but as I said- earlier when I used to right click and save files,the files were saved as a pdf.Anyways I would be glad if you could help me out for downloading the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at the page in firebug I do not see a PDF. I see a webpage (in HTML, and with a title which ends in PDF, but which is build in HTML).

Best guess: they replaced the PDF with something different, which makes it impossible to download the PDF.

Screenshot of webpage in firefox with firebug console open:
[image: Screenshot of webpage in firefox with firebug console open]

What you can do is:

- Make a printscreen of each and every page. Optionally print those all to a PDF 'printer'
- Or change the left margin of the webpage to zero (fr me it defaulted to 418px), and then print page by page to a PDF writer.
  (Failing to adjust the margin causes page which only partially fits on regular A4 sized format. After changing the margin to 0 it fits nicely).
- Lastly, the cop out solution: They obviously made this page from a PDF source. You can always ask them to email you those PDFs.

Comment: It is loaded as image files, each page as a seperate image, with Inspect/Firebug you can easily find the direct image URLs and download

Comment: @YisroelTech how exactly? I am trying to download form a js.viewer

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is a pdf stored on Google Drive. If you pop it out (the square with an arrow in the top corner) you can click details and it says

> DOWNLOAD PERMISSION
>
> Viewers cannot download

The drive Web viewer renders the PDF on the drive servers and just displays it on you screen, your computer never recives the PDF so unless there a hack, you can't download it.

EDIT: You may also consider using the contact form at http://www.thinkiit.in/contact and kindly ask for a download link. If they say no there's no harm done

Comment: +1 for contacting them and asking for a download link.